# How to use multiple places in Spring viewresolver?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

this is how I define the loaction of my jsp files:

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

But I have too many JSP files in one folder at the moment...I changed my directiory structure to this:

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/city/*.jsp
/WEB-INF/jsp/weather/*.jsp
```

How must I change my viewresolver so that both places are found?

Ask for more info if needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't change it at all, just return qualified view names, e.g.

`"city/tokyo"` or `"weather/partlyCloudy"`

Comment: Yeah that would be better, no need for boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the Sean Patrick Floyd answer is a better way to do this, but if you are not willing to use that technique, define two view resolvers, one with the prefix "/WEB-INF/jsp/city" and the other with the prefix "/WEB-INF/jsp/weather".

Comment: That does not work, since the InternalResourceViewResolver does not check whether the resource actually exists. Therefore it will try to load the resource under the prefix that comes first. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html