# Spring MVC template resolver for JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm actually using Spring MVC, Spring Security and Thymeleaf.
How can I add the possibility to use jsp in my application ?

I've try to add these lines into my 
applications.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=classpath:/templates/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

The idea is that i want to be able to use jsp in the folder
src/main/resources/templates/jsp/
And  thymeleaf html files in src/main/resources/templates/thymeleaf/

My controller

```
@Controller
public class HelloJSP {
    @RequestMapping("/jsp")
    public String helloJSP() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

And my hello.jsp is in the folder src/main/ressources/templates/jsp/hello.jsp

Do I need to register somewhere jsp ressources in the Spring security ressource handler ?

Comment: I refer specifically to configure "multiple view resolver" but I do not know how to do without breaking the automatic configuration of spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix would be

Change

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=classpath:/templates/jsp/
```

into

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=classpath:/templates/
```

Whenever you wanna create a view from jsp or thymeleaf, add prefix there such as "jsp/my_jsp_page" and "thymeleaf/my_thymeleaf_page"

Reference: [How to use multiple places in Spring viewresolver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527607/how-to-use-multiple-places-in-spring-viewresolver)

Comment: Actually I need two suffix too but set a parameter let me add just one suffix.

Comment: If you must use two suffixes, I found [this](https://blog.frankel.ch/chaining-url-view-resolvers-in-spring-mvc) which is not a small fix, yet it's not a lot either. Let me know if it works.